# Accessing object's properties in for loop produces 'any' type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Person {
   name: string;
   country: string;
}

const key = 'name';

const person: Person = {
   name: 'John Smith',
   country: 'Australia',
};

console.log(person[key]);   // "John Smith"
```

the above code compiles, but I got an compiler error if I use a for loop to enumerate the keys as:

```
function PrintPerson(p: Person) {
   for (const key of Object.keys(p)) {
      console.log(p[key]); // <-------compile error, Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'
   }
}

const person: Person = {
   name: 'John Smith',
   country: 'Australia',
};

PrintPerson(person);
```

I don't understand, why I can use `person[key]` but cannot use `p[key]`, aren't they the same thing? the error also says " Element implicitly has an 'any' type error...", but I didn't define `any` type anywhere, where does it come from?

Comment: try this way `for (const key of Object.keys(p) as Array<keyof Person>)`

Comment: @SaiManoj but why TS compiler says "Element implicitly has an 'any' type"? I didn't declare `any` type